# use redux in vanilla js application

Tags: javascript, json, redux, web-applications

I am working on vanilla JS application. I need to start a new project whereby I need to redo a checkout page. I plan to create different controller components to deal with different logic on page e.g. delivery method component, user addresses component, basket update component etc.

I need some guidelines on whether I should use redux for state management or use custom events handler to update state of different component. More specifically I am trying to find whether using redux would be a heavyweight implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: From my tests redux is very lightweight but you need to add a lot of code to achieve anything. Other solutions that require less code are heavier. Just take a look at redux source code almost no code.

Comment: Thanks @Xesenix Found a intresting post here: https://k94n.com/gordux-js-the-redux-pattern-in-vanilla-js

Comment: maybe even better check this course by redux author https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-implementing-store-from-scratch it basicly show how to build redux from scratch

Comment: https://dev.to/chovy/state-management-into-its-own-module-in-vanilla-javascript-58mf